# Placeholder in Rails that will actually submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I know how to make a placeholder in a rails form, but is there a way to put something in it that will actually submit something? Something like `<%= f.email_field, :email, (element here): <%= current_user.email %> %>` Help would be much appreciated. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: what exactly yr trying to make ?

Comment: @7urkm3n an email field that will have a value already in it, but not a placeholder. So if the user doesn't type anything into it, it will still return a value of <%= current_user.email %> Does that make sense?

Comment: can you show your current view, where would you want to use that,on edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding a value it should work as you want. Example below

```
<%= f.email_field, :email, value: current_user.email %>
```