# How to use ruby tags in placeholder: or value:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, placeholder

I am wondering how to use `<%= %>` tags in a `placeholder:` or `value:`
Ex. `<%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: <insert code here>` Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: you can find more here http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2005/10/21/using-named-placeholders-in-ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered for you already for this question

[Placeholder in Rails that will actually submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36853239/placeholder-in-rails-that-will-actually-submit)

Just adding a value it should work as you want. Example below

```
<%= f.email_field, :email, value: current_user.email %>
```